# Pre-receive hook to check the binary file

Tags: python, ruby, git, gitlab, hook

I am trying to restrict the binary file(dll, pdf, exe) committing in our GitLab instance. My moto is need to abort the commit if the commit have binary files. I have the code for aborting the commit in Python,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def scanDir(dirName):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirName):
        for fileName in files:
            if fileName.split('.')[-1] in ["txt","dll","pdf"]:
                return 1
    return 0
```

My problem in Gitlab have hooks file in ruby, My code is in python, So It doesn`t works in ruby code. ([How to load the python file in ruby hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46069393/how-to-load-the-python-file-in-ruby-hook))

Also I do not know what is **path** should I need to give in `def scanDir(dirName):` I tried my level best , But I can`t able do this in ruby because I newbie to ruby.

Can anyone help to add the hook to restrict the binary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GitLab hooks might be in any language](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/667c0a909bde1cf71f21d8ec9768e98b1c489030/doc/hooks/custom_hooks.md).

It’s unclear why you can’t just use your python code as is.

---

FWIW, the translated code would be:

```
def scan_dir(dir_name)
  Dir["#{dir_name}/**/*"].any? do |f|
    %w|.txt .pdf .dll|.include?(File.extname(f))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your guiding, What dir_name could I pass to check the files?

Comment: I am unsure about `GitLab`, but I think it would be a project root folder.

Comment: Ok, In your answer where the code returns 0 or 1 because there is no exit command, That`s why I asked

Comment: `1` and `0` in python are for truthy and falsey. In ruby, the result of the last line of a method is returned, hence the result of call to `any?` is returned.

Comment: Could you let me know the way to pass the argument to `scan_def` method? if the path is `/home/git/repositories/`

Comment: I have no clue what `scan_def` is. The argument is passed to the method as in literally all other languages: `method(argument)`. If an argument is the same in most calls, it might be made a default via `def scan_dir(dir_name = "/home/git/repositories/")` and the method might be called without an argument to enable default.

Comment: Above code is not working for me, I totally wrong calculated the workflow of the git and worked stupidly. I found a clue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26955973 to get the staged file in git by **ruby**. But don`t know how to use the answer in ruby code for my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46095928. Could you help me?